# Two questions about installing Visual Studio 2010 (Beta 2)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Question 1: Can I work with Visual Studio 2008 while installing it?

Question 2: Can I download the whole thing somewhere (but as an installable file or files, not an ISO)?

I know it's theoretically better not to run anything while it installs.  But my download speed is *extremely* slow, and it's wasting a lot of time waiting for this thing to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Probably, but if there were any problems with the installation it would be tough to know whether using VS2008 during the installation was the source of the problem.
2. Probably not.  There are tons of free ISO mounters out there, if that's your concern.  Downloading the install as a bunch of files wouldn't be faster.  If you're having problems downloading the ISO, look into using a download manager.

Comment: I started using VS 2008 about halfway through, when it was on the very long downloading-VS-2010 step.  No ill effects that I can see.  There was one reboot somewhere in the middle, and another one at the end, but neither one was an immediate, forced reboot, so I was able to save my work, reboot, and then continue.  My hat is off to Microsoft.

Comment: I think you had us all confused- I didn't know there was an install that includes a download step.  That step doesn't actually do anything but grab the bits, so I wouldn't expect any problems using VS2008 (or anything else) during that time.  Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: I was using VS 2008 during both the downloading part and the installing part.  The installer runs, downloads, and installs.  So yes, there was potential for concern.

Answer (score 1):

You cant run VS2008 while installation. Setup process will ask you at some point of installation to close any version of VS running on system.

The only option of full download in ISO, just burn a DVD and use it.

Comment: Yeah, i think it needs couple of restarts.

Answer (score 0):

The only option for downloading 'the whole thing' is to download the ISO. You can find free ISO extractors. Just extract the ISO, and install from there.

I wouldn't recommend running VS2008 when installing it. The install doesn't take **that** long. It does require 2 reboots during install though, which might be quite disruptive when you're trying to work

Comment: Stopping to reboot a time or two isn't anywhere near as disruptive as not being able to work at all.  At some points my download speed slowed to 5K/second or so.  We have a terrible connection where I work.

Comment: I'd guess your wasting more time commenting and posting/researching on SO/Web than what installing VS2010 would take..

Comment: I'm already installing VS2010.  So I was wondering if I could be running VS2008 at the same time rather than wasting time here.  If VS2010 installation were all that quick, I wouldn't have had time to post this question.  So thanks anyway.

Comment: You could download the ISO while working in VS2008, once you have that, the install doesn't take long

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Sander, installation wont take that much time. But I wonder if VS2010 installation needs internet for latest downloads during installation process.

Comment: Just hit the first reboot.  But hey, it's polite and asks instead of just killing everything.

Comment: @Zinx: if you download the ISO, you can install everything without internet connection